# Move uibuttons from outside of screen to their location

Tags: ios, swift

I have four uibuttons at the corners of the screen and a uiimage at the center of the screen.  I need these four buttons display hidden during load and when I tap on the image;

- top two buttons will move vertically from the outside of the screen and stop at top two corners (these should move from top),
- bottom two buttons will move vertically from the outside of the
  screen and stop at bottom two corners(these should move from bottom).
  Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the location of the UIButtons programatically outside the bounds of the screen. When the image is tapped, animate the buttons into view using UIAnimation.

Check out this tutorial that might help you: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76200/basic-uiview-animation-swift-tutorial

Comment: Beat me to it! Exactly what I was going to say, link and all ;)